# Range minimum queries when array is dynamic

Tags: arrays, algorithm, segment-tree, rmq

I have an array say A(0 indexed) of size 1.

I want to find minimum in array A between indexes k1 (k1>=0) and A.size()-1(i.e the last element).

Then I would insert the value : (minimum element in given range + some "random" constant) at the end of the array.Then I have another query to find minimum between indexes k2 and A.size()-1. I find that, insert the value : (minimum in the given range + another "random" constant) at the end. I have to do many such queries.

Say, I have N queries. Naive approach would take O(N^2).

Cannot use segment trees as array is not static. But, a clever way to do is make segment tree for size N+1 array; beforehand and fill the unknown values with infinity. This would give me O(Nlog N) complexity.

Is there any other method for NlogN complexity or even N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to use advanced data structures like tree here. Just a simple local variable and list will do it all:

Create an empty list(say `minList`).

Start from the `end` index and go till the `start` index of the *initially given* array, put the minimum values (till that index from the `end`) at the front of the list(i.e. do `push_front`).

Lets say the provided array is:

```
70 10 50 40 60 90 20 30
```

So the resultant `minList` will be:

```
10 10 20 20 20 20 20 30
```

After doing that, you **only** need to keep track of the minimum among *newly appended* elements in the continuously modifying array(say, `minElemAppended`).

Lets say you get `k = 5` and `randomConstant` = -10, then

```
minElemAppended = minimum(minList[k-1] + randomConstant, minElemAppended)
```

By adopting this approach,

- You don't need to traverse the appended part of or even the initial given array.
- You have option not to append the elements at all.
- Time Complexity: `O(N)` to process `N` queries.
- Space Complexity: `O(N)` to store the `minList`

Comment: I have a version of this problem where k is not fixed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754633 Can anyone on this thread help me?