# Range Minimum Query for growing array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, rmq

I have an array A[0..n] and I need to find the minimum value in the interval A[k₀..n]. Based on that, the array is extended with a value A[n+1] and I need the minimum in A[k₁..n+1]. Again the array is extended with some A[n+2] and queried for the min in A[k₂..n+2]. Is there a way to do each query in O(1) time (after some preprocessing)?

Compared with this earlier question: [Range minimum queries when array is dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395294), a difference is that the queried interval start at varying positions k₀, k₁, k₂, ... The end of the queried interval is always the righmost end of the array. In my application I start with an empty array (n=0) so the preprocessing might be trivial. If this helps, in my application the new value used in the extension is always 1+(min returned by last query). But the positions k₀, k₁, k₂, ... depend on data outside of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that I know of to make both the addition of a new element and the query happen in `O(1)`, and it's probably impossible (though I'm not exactly sure how to prove this). But you can pretty easily make it happen in `O(log(n))` using a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). That's probably good enough for any practical application.